# Efficient way to save and reuse data in a ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working with a ruby gem which is essentially a business logic layer and runs custom rules after gathering data from an external service (via APIs).

This data gathered from external service is saved as an instance variable in one of my ruby classes and the logic just runs on it. Something like this:

```
@data = gather_data_from_service
```

During the local development, it is annoying to have to wait for 10 minutes just to grab this data each time I make some code changes and test it. Is there a way I can save and reuse this? Looking for some suggestions. Thanks!

Here's what the `gather_data_from_service` returns: (its a list of ruby objects)

```
[#MyLibrary::ClassA
    @id: 'xxx',
    @name: 'ppp', 
 #MyLibrary::ClassA
    @id: 'yo',
    @name,
 #MyLibrary::ClassA
   -----,
 #MyLibrary::ClassA
   -----]
```

PS: The data I gather from the service takes long it has to iterate over all of its resources and respond back (I don't think I have much control over improvements that can be made on this end).

Comment: Do bears deficate in the woods? There are tons of ways to save and cache data on a server on everything from the file system to memory based storage like redis or memcached or a database. Rails also has a built in cache system that can be used for low level caching.

Comment: @max Yeah, I wish I could use these cache/DB facilities. But I am just working on a ruby gem and just running  plain ruby code. The development effort is not using rails framework.

Comment: Still what alternatives have you actually looked at or evaluated? Just beause you are writing a gem outside of rails does not mean you can't have development dependencys like dalli or a database driver or implement a file system based cache. And why is this question tagged rails?

Comment: https://github.com/vcr/vcr is a pretty commonly used gem to record HTTP responses during testing and then use them as test fixtures.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options here but it basically boils down to have a fake or mock class.

One example is to write an adapter class around your data fetching which you can swap out for a fake loader. Assuming your API is JSON you could store some of the data in a JSON file and just load it like this:

```rb
class RemoteData
  def data
    @data = gather_data_from_service
  end
end

class MemoryData
  def data
    @data = fetch_data
  end

  def fetch_data
    JSON.parse(File.read('path/to/fixtures/data.json'))
  end
end
```

If your response data is more complex, you could also think about writing wrapper classes around it. And then you can just set the class depending on the environment. This only works for queries. If you need to test commands too, you could write a spy class.

```rb
class Spy
  cattr_accessor :data do
    []
  end

  def post(params)
    data << params
  end
end

spy = Spy.new
spy.post(hello: :world)
Spy.deliveries.include?({ hello: :world })
```

Other options could be to write a fake like the [fake_stripe gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/fake_stripe) or use [Webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) to mock HTTP request.

Here is an explanation of the differences between [mock, fake and spy too](https://www.futurelearn.com/info/blog/stubs-mocks-spies-rspec#types-of-test-double).

### Edit

You could still use some sort of mock or fake you just need to first think about some way of serializing the data. The most extensible and readable way would still be to serialize this to JSON. You could implement this yourself like this with e.g. e monkey patch.

```rb
class MyClass::A
  def serialize
    {}.tap do |result|
      instance_variables.map do |var|
        result[var.to_s.delete("@")] = instance_variable_get(var)
      end
    end
  end
end

MyClass::A.new(id: 1).serialize
# { id: 1 }
```

A more bare metal approach could be to use for instance [Marshal dump](https://blog.appsignal.com/2019/03/26/object-marshalling-in-ruby.html).

```rb
A = Struct.new(:id)
serialized = Marshal.dump(A.new(id: 1))
# "\x04\bS:\x06A\x06:\aid{\x06;\x06i\x06"
Marshal.load(serialized)
# => #<struct A id={:id=>1}>
```

Comment: I think this answer works great if I had a json response. But my actual `gather_data_from_service` returns a list of Ruby objects that looks something like this:

`[#MyLibrary::ClassA 
      @id: 'xxx', 
      @name: 'ppp', 
  #MyLibrary::ClassA 
      @id: 'yo', 
      @name,
  ------
  -----
]`

These objects are pretty deeply nested.

Comment: Can you give an example how this data looks or which gem you use?

Comment: Is the gem you use open source to have a look?

Comment: I just updated the summary above to reflect how the data looks. It def looks weird in the comment. 
Nah, I wish I could share the library. But, it's pretty much closed source

Comment: Updated my answer, have a look at the edit.